# Expecting a certain format

Tags: python

So i'm trying to write a code for a router terminal simulator. And I'm using `raw_input` to read from the keyboard.

The problem is that I want to do a specific action when the user writes a sequence that matches this pattern: **"<1-100> permit"**, so in order to accomplish this I wrote an if of this type:

```
if input == "%d permit" %number:
    print 'Do this'
```

I want the number to be a value in the range of 1-100. I created a list with the `range(1,100)` function but I don't know how to check this condition inside my if.

I solved the problem however with the use of split function and some other conditions, but I can't really get over this idea and I want to find a solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry but what is the problem with your code?

Comment: Do you want to do different actions based on what the number is? If so, a better idea might be to - create a map (or even a list) of 'Actions' and use that index rather than trying to do `if XXXX` 100 times. But better if you can explain a bit  what you want to do. Because the solution will likely be different (and perhaps shorter too)

Comment: @AntonvBR The problem is that %number is not defined and I don't know how to define it in order to satisfy the condition later inside the 'if'.

Comment: @gabhijit I want the same action for all the numbers inside 1-100 range. This is what i want to do: a router terminal simulator when you can enter different commands. i.e: '1 permit host 10.0.0.1', '1 permit ?' (show command)

Answer (score 1):

```
if input == "%d permit" %number and number in range(1,101):
    print 'Do this'
```

Comment: I tried this approach, but I have to define the var 'number' and this leads me to total confusion

Comment: What about:   number = 0

Comment: it will not be overwrite, it will be 0 and will not satisfy the if statement

Comment: Then change the code and write something like `number = int(input())` and check if it is in range

Comment: I can't change the code.. It's a terminal that I'm trying to simulate with predefined commands (1 permit host 1.1.1.1, 15 deny host 1.2.3.4).. Your suggestion will imply 2 different inputs, and I need just want raw_input at a time

Comment: Then, try: `if int(input.split(" ")[0]) in range(1,101):`

Answer (score 0):

Use `re.match(pattern, value)`:

```
import re
[...]
if re.match(r"(\d\d?|100) permit", input):
    do_something()
```

And the variable `input` will override the built-in function `input()`, so change the name to something else.

**EDIT:** As you don't want to use RegExp, you can split the string, pass it to `int` and then see if it's in the range.

```
if 1 <= int(input.split(" ")[0]) <= 100:
    do_something()
```

Comment: I avoid using match because I'm new to programming/Python and I didn't fully understand this function. The problem is that your code works for 10-100, not 1-100. 
Thank you for replying! Your solution is also valid, but I'm not looking for this approach (using re.match)

Comment: C This was the solution I was reffering to in the original post. I solved the problem by splitting the string, but it drives me crazy that I couldn't solve the problem as I expected (with if input == "%d permit" %number and number in range(1,101):, as Attersson posted earlier)